# I am running following code on bluehost server. mail() function sending email but doesn't return any value

Tags: php, html

```
 <?php 
 $m = ""; 
 $to = "anymail@gmail.com";                     
 $from = "anymail@mydomainname.com";
 $subject = 'subject';
 $message = "Any Message";
 $headers = "From: $from\n"; 
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
 if ( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) { 
     $m = "Email sent successfully"; exit(); 
 }else { 
     $m = "Email can't be sent.";exit();
 }  
 exit(); 
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
 <head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Untitled Document</title></head>
 <body>
 <h2> 
 <?php  
   echo $m; 
 ?> </h2>
 </body></html>
```

I am unable to get confirmation. Could anyone point out the problem?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: <?php $m = ""; $to = "anymail@gmail.com";      $from = "anymail@mydomainname.com";$subject = 'subject';$message = "Any Message";$headers = "From: $from\n"; $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";if ( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) { $m = "Email sent successfully"; exit(); }else { $m = "Email can't be sent.";exit();}  exit(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Untitled doc</title></head><body>
<h2> <?php  echo $m; ?> </h2></body></html> I am unable to get confirmation. Could anyone point out the problem?

Comment: I am new user, using stackflow first time. I dont know why my code didn't appear with question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code, its the `exit()` which stops the execution and not printing value of `$m`

```
if ( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) { 
   $m = "Email sent successfully"; 
   //exit(); 
}else { 
   $m = "Email can't be sent.";
   //exit();
}  
//exit();
```

Comment: ohh. How I could be so stupid? I had the same (exit) problem with other webpage when I just started coding in php and after detecting solution after 1-2 hours, I thought that I would never forget. But... By the way thanks a lot. I really appreciate !!!